# NUXT SSR mounted hook

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Is there anyway we can access DOM elements in SSR using Nuxt? The mounted hook is not called in SSR and created hook doesn't have the DOM loaded yet.

Comment: What do you need to achieve ?

Comment: @ajobi I have to load a library using customized DOM elements. The library is implemented in d3. I cannot access any of the components of Nuxt client from a webpage so I will have to figure out a way to render it from server side

Answer (score -1):

in both of them you can access the DOM. You just need an `if()` statement to check if you are on the server side or client side

```
created(){
   if(!process.server){
      //do stuff on client side
   }
}
```

Comment: I added a route to Nuxt.renderRoute as well, but its not calling mounted when I access that route from a webpage